# kernel-default-devel for Arch

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to write kernel module on machine running Arch Linux. I wasn't able to locate and import 'generated/autoconf.h' (in previous version of kernels 'linux/autoconf.h' or 'linux/config.h').

I've already installed 'linux-headers' for other includes. Sadly there is no entry about 'kernel-default-devel', which apparently contains this particular header file, in AUR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers for the `linux` package are in `linux-headers`:

```
# pacman -Fy autoconf.h
core/linux-headers
    usr/lib/modules/5.9.9-arch1-1/build/include/generated/autoconf.h
core/linux-lts-headers
    usr/lib/modules/5.4.78-1-lts/build/include/generated/autoconf.h
extra/linux-hardened-headers
    usr/lib/modules/5.9.8.a-1-hardened/build/include/generated/autoconf.h
extra/linux-zen-headers
    usr/lib/modules/5.9.9-zen1-1-zen/build/include/generated/autoconf.h
```

```
$ pacman -Qo /usr/src/linux/include/generated/autoconf.h
/usr/lib/modules/5.9.9-arch1-1/build/include/generated/autoconf.h is owned by linux-headers
```

"kernel-default-devel" is a package name invented by Red Hat. It has no meaning in Arch, nor any other distribution that is not from the RH/CentOS/Fedora family.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I'm new with Arch Linux and kernel module develepment. The problem was not compiling the code with sudo. Running `sudo cc -I/usr/src/linux/include/ -Wall -c main.c` links `autoconf.h` correctly. However, it seems that /asm folder with headers is not present. I found  (with pacman) that there is /asm-generic folder with required files. Is there some way I can tell compiler to use asm as abbrevation of asm-generic?

Comment: It has nothing to do with sudo. The headers are world-accessible, and if you for some reason need sudo to access them, that's usually a bigger problem, not a solution.

Comment: The system is pure installation of latest Arch. Maybe I did something wrong when setting up the user I'm working on. `useradd "username"` `mkhomedir_helper "username"`
`pacman --sync sudo`
`pacman --sync vi`
`usermod --append --groups wheel "username"`
`visudo` (uncommented '%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL')
`su - "username"`
`sudo whoami`

Comment: I just said it has nothing to do with sudo. The files in /usr/src are accessible to all users, regardless of what group they're in. You didn't mention whether you are getting any error messages from cc/cpp when trying to use those includes, nor what the error messages are.

Comment: I understand. The only error is that autoconf header file was not found. I'll need to read more documentation on how to compile modules properly and include needed files. Thanks you for your effort.